# Embed ACE Editor into tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-tools, ace-editor

I have to jsfiddles

1. [HTML with tabs](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6xBV/2/)
2. [Embedded ACE Editor](http://jsfiddle.net/7y5Zr/2/)

Below are complete codes per warning

### HTML with tabs

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- tab "panes" -->
    <div class="panes">
      <div id="pane1">Tab1 content</div>
      <div id="pane2">Tab2 content</div>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.css**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:50px 80px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
}

.panes div {
    display:none;
    padding:15px 10px;
    border-top :1px solid #999;
    height:500px;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:#fff;
}

 ul.tabs {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 !important;
    padding:0;
    height:30px;
}

ul.tabs li {
    float:left;
    text-indent:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 !important;
}

ul.tabs a {
    font-size:11px;
    display:block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height:30px;
    width: 134px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#333;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

 ul.tabs a:active {
    outline:none;
}

ul.tabs a:hover {
    color:red;
}

ul.tabs a.current, ul.tabs a.current:hover, ul.tabs li.current a {
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor:default !important;
    color:#000 !important;
}

.panes .pane {
    display:none;
}

#pane2 { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 80px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

---

### HTML with ACE Editor embedded

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    <script src="http://d1n0x3qji82z53.cloudfront.net/src-min-noconflict/ace.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="pane2">
    function foo(items){
      var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
      return x;
    }
  </div>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.css** - is the same

**test.js**

```
var editor = ace.edit("pane2");
editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/textmate");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

---

So, my goal is combine those two pages into one, where in first tab there is some content, and in second one there should be editor itself. When I do it as following

### HTML with tabs and ACE Editor in second tab

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://d1n0x3qji82z53.cloudfront.net/src-min-noconflict/ace.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- tab "panes" -->
    <div class="panes">
      <div id="pane1">Tab1 content</div>
      <div id="pane2">
          function foo(items){
            var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
            return x;
          }
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
      });
    </script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.css** - is the same

**test.js** - is the same

then Tab 1 shows content correctly **but there's no editor in tab 2**. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/CzLnW/1/) is the jsfiddle of non-working code.

Any hints, help, ready-to-go code that fix the problem are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never ever write css like   `.panes div {display:none};`:)
Ace mostly consists of divs, and this rule hides everything inside Ace.
You can use `.panes>.pane` instead.
for working demo see http://plnkr.co/edit/fX3ODmSgguQHXq9daGPA?p=preview

Btw version of ace you used is very old, use newer one from jsdelivr or cdn.js or download from github.

Comment: Dude, that is so awesome. Honestly, I just copypasted that css above from jquery-tools example of tabs. It worked perfectly anyway. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/CzLnW/3/

This is probably not the best solution but it may come in handy anyway.

I was having some trouble getting it to work with your tab based system, I ended up grabbing my external hard drive and grabbing a mobile tabbed web browser experiment project.

I tried embedding the ace editor directly into each tab, but that wasn't working. So you may want to try and embed it into a website and link it via iframe. It's not the best solution, but the best I could come up with at this time.

JQuery/JavaScript:

```
var websiteframe = '<iframe src="http://bing.com/" width="100%" height="100%" allowtransparency="true" frameBorder="0">Your browser does not support IFRAME</iframe>';
var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
var tabTitle = $('#tab_title');
tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
    tabCounter = 2;

function addTab() {
    var label = tabTitle.val() || "" + tabCounter,
        id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
        li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label)),
        websiteframe = '<iframe src="http://duckduckgo.com/" width="100%" height="100%" allowtransparency="true" frameBorder="0">Your browser does not support IFRAME</iframe>';
    tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
    tabs.append("<div align='center' id='" + id + "'>" + websiteframe + "</div>");
    tabs.tabs("refresh");
    tabCounter++;
}

$("#add_tab").click(function () {
    addTab();
});

// close icon: removing the tab on click
tabs.delegate( "span.ui-icon-close", "click", function() {
    var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
    $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
    tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
});

tabs.bind( "keyup", function( event ) {
    if ( event.altKey && event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.BACKSPACE ) {
        var panelId = tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-active" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
        $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
        tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, it's sort of solution too, even though I'm not sure if iframed DOM elements will be accessible from master document. Thanks. I'll keep an eye on my question if any other solutions show up, before accepting.